# Cant check for resources

Tags: python

I am working on a code to make a coffee machine simulator and I want to add the money paid from each transaction to the money resources in the machine and I can't
PLease help me do it
Thanks
Here is my code:

```
menu = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee_l": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
    "money":0
}

import os

def check(drink):
    if drink == 'espresso':
        if resources['water'] >= 50 and resources['coffee'] >= 18:
            return "enough"
        elif resources['water'] <= 50:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] <= 18:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
    elif drink=='latte':
        if resources['water'] >= 200 and resources['milk'] >= 150 and resources['coffee'] >= 24:
            return "enough"
        elif resources['water'] < 50:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] < 18:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
        elif resources['milk'] < 150:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough milk."
            
    elif drink=='cappuccino':
        if resources['water'] >= 250 and resources['milk'] >= 100 and resources['coffee'] >= 24:
            return "enough"
        elif resources['water'] < 250:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] < 24:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
        elif resources['milk'] < 100:
            return "​Sorry there is not enough milk."

def money():
    quarter=0.25
    dime=0.1
    nickel=0.05
    pennie=0.01
    qu=float(input("Inset quarters: "))
    di=float(input("Insert dimes: "))
    ni=float(input("Insert nickels: "))
    pen=float(input("Insert pennies: "))
    total_paid=qu*quarter+di*dime+ni*nickel+pen*pennie
    return total_paid

report=f"Water: {resources['water']}ml\nMilk: {resources['milk']}ml\nCoffee: {resources['coffee']}ml\nMoney: {resources['money']}$"

while True:
    print("Welcome to the coffee machine.")
    m="Espresso = 1.5$\nLatte = 2.5$\nCappuccino = 3.0$\n"
    print(m)
    choice=input("​What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino)(e/l/c): ")
    if choice=='e':
        # ~ e_w=menu['espresso']['ingredients']['water']
        # ~ e_c=menu['espresso']['ingredients']['coffee']
        # ~ #print(e_w)
        chk=check('espresso')
        print(chk)
        if chk=="enough":
            mo=money()
            if mo == menu['espresso']['cost']:
                print('Here is your coffee')
            elif mo > menu['espresso']['cost']:
                print(f'Here is your coffee, and here is your change {round(mo-menu["espresso"]["cost"], 2)} $')
                
                print(f"Money in machine is: {resources['money']}")
            elif mo < menu['espresso']['cost']:
                print(f'​Sorry that\'s not enough money. Money refunded.')
        resources['money']=mo+resources['money']
        print(f"Money in machine is: {round(resources['money'],2)}")
    elif choice=='l':
        chk=check('latte')
        print(chk)
        if chk=="enough":
            mo=money()
            if mo == menu['latte']['cost']:
                print('Here is your coffee')
            elif mo > menu['latte']['cost']:
                print(f'Here is your coffee, and here is your change {mo-menu["latte"]["cost"]} $')
                resources['money']=mo+resources['money']
                print(f"Money in machine is: {resources['money']}")
            elif mo < menu['latte']['cost']:
                print(f'​Sorry that\'s not enough money. Money refunded.')
    elif choice=='c':
        chk=check('cappuccino')
        print(chk)
        if chk=="enough":
            money()
            mo=money()
            if mo == menu['cappuccino']['cost']:
                print('Here is your coffee')
            elif mo > menu['cappuccino']['cost']:
                print(f'Here is your coffee, and here is your change {mo-menu["cappuccino"]["cost"]} $')
                resources['money']=mo+resources['money']
                print(f"Money in machine is: {resources['money']}")
            elif mo < menu['cappuccino']['cost']:
                print(f'​Sorry that\'s not enough money. Money refunded.')
    elif choice=='report':
        print(report)   
    elif choice=='off':
        break
```

I tried to add it under each if statement in the while loop and it worked but when i entered report there is no money in the machine.

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about the [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) API, but not for questions about games written with Python.

Comment: Please post an output of your program run and let us know what you expect it to do instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that there has been a answer to your question while I was testing out your code and doing some refactoring.  Some of the bits I noticed were that some of the tests did not seem to provide the correct answers.  Also, it seemed like there was a bit of repeated instructions happening for the various selections that could be streamlined.  With that in mind, I offer up another possible route for your code with the following refactored version.

```
import os

menu = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee_l": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
    "money":0
}

def check(drink):
    response = "Enough"
    if drink == 'espresso':
        if resources['water'] <= 50:
            response = "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] <= 18:
            response = "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
    elif drink ==' latte':
        if resources['water'] < 50:
            response = "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] < 18:
            response = "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
        elif resources['milk'] < 150:
            response = "​Sorry there is not enough milk."      
    elif drink == 'cappuccino':
        if resources['water'] < 250:
            response = "​Sorry there is not enough water."
        elif resources['coffee'] < 24:
            response = "​Sorry there is not enough coffee."
        elif resources['milk'] < 100:
            response = "​Sorry there is not enough milk."
    return response

def money():
    quarter = 0.25
    dime = 0.1
    nickel = 0.05
    pennie = 0.01
    qu = float(input("Inset quarters: "))
    di = float(input("Insert dimes: "))
    ni = float(input("Insert nickels: "))
    pen = float(input("Insert pennies: "))
    total_paid = qu * quarter + di * dime + ni * nickel + pen * pennie
    return total_paid

def make_drink(drink):              # Added this function to consume the resources for the type of drink ordered
    if drink == "espresso":
        resources['water']  -= 50
        resources['coffee'] -= 18
    elif drink == "latte":
        resources['water']  -= 50
        resources['coffee'] -= 18
        resources['milk']   -= 150
    elif drink == "cappuccino":
        resources['water']  -= 250
        resources['coffee'] -= 18
        resources['milk']   -= 100
    else:
        print("Not sure what drink was made")
    return

def replenish():
    resources['water']  = 300
    resources['milk']   = 200
    resources['coffee'] = 100
    return

while True:
    print("Welcome to the coffee machine.")
    m = "Espresso = $1.50\nLatte = $2.50\nCappuccino = $3.00\n"
    selection = ""
    print(m)
    choice=input("​What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino)(e/l/c): ")
    # Store the choice in a selection variable to streamline the choice function call
    if choice == 'e':
        selection = 'espresso'
    elif choice == 'l':
        selection = 'latte'
    elif choice == 'c':
        selection = 'cappuccino'
    elif choice == 'report':
        print("Water:" + str(resources['water']) + "\nMilk:" + str(resources['milk']) + "\nCoffee:" + str(resources['coffee']) + "\nMoney: $" + str(resources['money']))
    elif choice == 'replenish':
        replenish()             # Add a function to replenish resources
    elif choice == 'off':
        break
    if choice in ['c', 'e', 'l']:
        chk = check(selection)
        print(chk)
        if chk == "Enough":
            mo=money()
            if mo == menu[selection]['cost']:
                make_drink(selection)
                print('Here is your ', selection)
            elif mo > menu[selection]['cost']:
                make_drink(selection)
                print(f'Here is your ', selection, ', and here is your change $', "{0:.2f}".format(round(mo-menu[selection]["cost"], 2)))
                mo = menu[selection]['cost']
            elif mo < menu[selection]['cost']:
                print(f'​Sorry that\'s not enough money. Money refunded.')
                mo = 0
        resources['money']=mo+resources['money']
    print("Money in machine is: $", "{0:.2f}".format(resources['money']))
    selection = ""
```

Forgive me for this being a bit verbose, but following are some of the highlights of this refactored code.

- Instead of repeating a lot of the same resource checks and monetary adjustments, an additional variable called "selection" was added to be used for  function calls and as an index subscript, which allowed for the streamlining of testing and function calls.
- Some of the tests for monetary amounts needed follow up adjustment of the actual money being added to the machine so that the correct money was added, or not added.
- Instead of keeping a separate report variable, the contents and functionality of the report value is just embedded within the printing of the report when requested.
- In testing the program, I noticed that there was actually no consumption of resources occurring (just testing), so a function was added to consume the resources for the appropriate drink selection.
- And just to round out the process, a replenishment option and function was added when resources begin to run out.

Following is some testing output at the terminal when running this program.

```
@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Coffee$ python3 Coffee.py 
Welcome to the coffee machine.
Espresso = $1.50
Latte = $2.50
Cappuccino = $3.00

What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino)(e/l/c): c
Enough
Inset quarters: 12
Insert dimes: 4
Insert nickels: 0
Insert pennies: 0
Here is your  cappuccino , and here is your change $ 0.40
Money in machine is: $ 3.00
Welcome to the coffee machine.
Espresso = $1.50
Latte = $2.50
Cappuccino = $3.00

What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino)(e/l/c): report
Water:50
Milk:100
Coffee:82
Money: $3.0
Money in machine is: $ 3.00
Welcome to the coffee machine.
Espresso = $1.50
Latte = $2.50
Cappuccino = $3.00

What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino)(e/l/c):
```

No doubt, there could be some more polishing of the code, but I believe this heads you in the direction you want to go.

Anyway, give this code a tryout if you desire and see if it helps answer some of your questions and meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code a lot.
It worked but i have 2 problems
When i enter 'e' or 'l' or 'c' 
I don't want to have the 'Enough' anymore, I replaced it with an empty string but it adds an empty line and i don't want that, i want it to go directly to the money function.

Comment: Hi.  Saw your question on not wanting to print "Enough".  I guess what you could do is immediately after the "chk = check(selection)" statement is add "if chk != "Enough":", indent the print(chk) statement so that it is conditioned by the "if" statement, and then change the next statement from if chk == "Enough": to just an "else:" statement with the testing for the literal "Enough" already has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable report is a fixed string. This line:

```
report=f"Water: {resources['water']}ml\nMilk: {resources['milk']}ml\nCoffee: {resources['coffee']}ml\nMoney: {resources['money']}$"
```

is executed exactly once and will set report to the string with the values at the time of the execution. What you want instead is a function that, when called, will build the string based on the current resuorces.

```
def report(resources):
    return f"Water: {resources['water']}ml\nMilk: {resources['milk']}ml\nCoffee: {resources['coffee']}ml\nMoney: {resources['money']}$"
```

Unrelated to your question, but I cannot leave this unmentioned: All your functions should use the data from the dictionary you define at the beginning. For isntance, your check function should look like below and not have any specific numbers in them:

```
def check(drink):
    for ingredient, required_amount in menu[drink]["ingredients"].items():
        if resources[ingredient] < required_amount:
            return f"Sorry, there is not enough {ingredient}"
    return "enough"
```

This will allow the function to work with new or changed coffee variations without being altered, whereas in your current code, every change has to be done at multiple places.

Last comment: Does your machine accept coins that are broken in half or why are you converting to float as opposed to int?